# How to combine the Tensorflow datasets and Keras preprocessing functions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Is there a way to use Keras' image preprocessing functions with the Tensorflow's datasets?

Here's the code I've got:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def load_image(file_path):
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(file_path)
    return tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)

def augment(img):
    return tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation(img, 360.0, fill_mode='reflect')

filepaths = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(os.path.join("train_images", "*.jpg"), shuffle=False)
images = filepaths.map(load_image).map(augment, num_parallel_calls=4)

image = next(iter(images))
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Tensor
```

That's because the `load_img` function expects a string as its first parameter while Tensorflow's dataset passes a Tensor object to the `map`.

What is the correct way of mixing and matching these APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found was to move the loading process of the images and augmentation into a generator function and use that as the source for the dataset:

```
import glob
import tensorflow as tf

def load_image(file_path):
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(file_path)
    return tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)

def augment(img):
    return tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation(img, 360.0, fill_mode='reflect')

def generator():
    for fp in glob.glob("train_images/*.jpg"):
        image = load_image(fp)
        yield augment(image)

images = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, tf.float32)

image = next(iter(images))
```